# How to remove leading and ending semicolons and whitespace

Tags: r, regex

i want to replace all semicolons by gsubbing in a data.frame.

For that i used this regex:

```
(^[;\\s]+)|([;\\s]+$)
gsub("(^[;\\s]+)|([;\\s]+$)", "", x)
```

in principle it works, but it also matches leading "s"-characters. I.E. "symmetrisch" becomes "ymmetrisch".

```
> gsub("(^[;\\s]+)|([;\\s]+$)", "", "Symmetrisch")
[1] "Symmetrisch"
> gsub("(^[;\\s]+)|([;\\s]+$)", "", "symmetrisch")
[1] "ymmetrisch"
```

What's wrong with the expression here?

Comment: There is no escaping inside square brackets, that's why your "\\s" si taken as "\" or "s"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[;\\s]` pattern does not match a whitespace because you are using the default TRE regex flavor, and the backslash inside a bracket expression in TRE matches a literal backslash.

There are two solutions. You can still use a TRE regex engine if you replace `\s` with `[:space:]` (that matches any whitespace) or `[:blank:]` (only matches horizontal whitespace) POSIX character classes:

```
gsub("^[;[:space:]]+|[;[:space:]]+$", "", "symmetrisch")
```

You can also switch to the PCRE engine:

```r
gsub("^[;\\s]+|[;\\s]+$", "", "symmetrisch", perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/8p6hDY). Both code lines output `[1] "symmetrisch"`.

**NOTE**: parentheses are redundant in your regex, hence I removed them.